# Best Way to Subtract User Inputted Date in Cell From a Set Date (Day/Month) Irregardless of the Year

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to establish the best way to write a formula to take a date that is inputted in a cell by a user and subtract it from the last day of the month (the due date), not taking into account what year it is.  The cell that contains the formula will be in another cell, pointing at the user inputted date cell.

I have 12 columns running across with each with one of the months of the calendar year.  In each column for the corresponding month is where the user will input the date they completed a task.  I would like to subtract their input from the last day of the corresponding month in that column.  I want to reuse this spreadsheet every year, so I do not want to account for the year in my formula.  I hope this will prevent me having to update the formulas each year.

An example would be if the user inputted 2/24/17 into C7, because the column C is the column for February, I would like the result to be -3 (I am not worried about leap years at this point).  If they inputted 3/11/17 into the same cell (C7), they would get a result of 11, because the date is 11 days past the due date.

Here is the formula that I started to use, but I believe it is relative to the current year.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C7),"",C7-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(1)+2,1)-1))
```

Here is a link to a picture of my spreadsheet.  Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Calendar Spreadsheet]

**Solution**
Changed YEAR(TODAY()) to YEAR(target cell).  My new formula looks like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C7),"",C7-(DATE(YEAR(C7),MONTH(1)+2,1)-1))
```

Comment: For any month but Februar you can hardcode it as DAY(EOMONTH(month,0)) -
 DAY(finished) - for february you need the leap-year so it is not year() independent... but you can get that by modifying TODAY() towards FEBRUAR and then try EOMONTH on it...

Comment: If you want your formula to be relative to the year in C7, change `YEAR(TODAY())` to `YEAR(C7)`.

Comment: You say "I would like to subtract their input from the last day of the corresponding month"....but your formula seems to indicate that the subtraction is the other way round? Please give some sample required results

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while since I first set up this formula.  I thought that this formula found the month after the month they would be inputting into and then subtracted one day, giving the last day of the correct month.  I figured there is a likely a much better way to do this than I was trying to before.

Comment: So if date in C7 is 22nd January what result do you want?

Comment: So if C7 was the Jan. column (it is actually the feb. column) and the user inputed 1/22/17, then I would like the cell containing the formula to display -9.  The cell containing the formula is under the "productivity" section on the far right of my worksheet.  This would tell me that they completed the task 9 days before the due date, the last day of the month for that column.

Comment: Then try using this formula `=IF(C7="","",C7-EOMONTH(C7,0))`

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  I was not aware of the EOMONTH function.

Comment: I apologize, as I played with it more, I realized this isn't quite what I was looking for.  I would like the formula to be able to display a positive value if they are inputting a date that is late.  So in this instance if C7 is the column for Feb. and they input a date of 3/11/17, I would like the formula to display a positive 11.  The formula with EOMONTH will just subtract the 3/11 from the end of March (giving a result of -20) instead of a positive 11 because the user inputted a March date in the Feb. column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(C7="","",C7-EOMONTH(C7,-1))
```

(based on @[barry houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini)'s [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067973/best-way-to-subtract-user-inputted-date-in-cell-from-a-set-date-day-month-irre#comment83110343_48067973) and subsequent OP clarification via a Comment).